# Does Powershell's -UseDefaultCredentials use Kerberos?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-devops, kerberos

In Azure DevOps services, when you connect an agent to the server, you have different types of ways to authenticate to the server. You can [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent) for example, about connecting a Linux agent, that you have these 4 types:

- Alternate (Basic authentication)
- PAT
- Negotiate - Connect as a user other than the signed-in user via a scheme such as Kerberos or NTLM.
- Integrated - Not supported in Linux

The integrated type is mentioned in the [page about connecting a Windows agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent) as "Windows default credentials"

Bare with me please.

In my organization, we have a Active Directory domain with a Single-Sign-On, I suppose it uses Kerberos as the authentication protocol. Sometimes I use Powershell scripts to access the API of our internal Azure DevOps Server, and I use the `-UseDefaultCredentials` flag so the user won't have to enter username and password - it will just authenticate based on the logged-in user.

That got me thinking that the `-UseDefaultCredentials` flag is using Kerberos to authenticate.

But from the above, it seems that Integrated is using "Default credentials", which is something else than "Negotiate" which uses Kerberos.

Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

The `UseDefaultCredentials` flag tells the underlying system to try and use the caller's SSO credentials, which in most cases is the credential used to log into the system interactively or otherwise.

Strictly speaking it does not indicate which protocol to use. What it's actually saying is "dear system internals: please figure it out for me". The way this works is by selecting the `negotiate` protocol, which as it's name suggests negotiates the use of specific authentication protocols based on the client credentials as well as information from the server. This is called the `SPNEGO` protocol. It is transparent to the caller.

SPNEGO is fairly simple in nature. The client has a list of known authentication protocols (Kerberos, NTLM, etc.) and will send that list to the server saying 'pick one please'. The server can select any of them and respond telling them what to use, and the client then goes and uses it. Fin.

SPNEGO is also relatively smart because it can reasonably predict what it thinks the server will accept and will attempt to optimistically provide a token up front using the first protocol in the list. So if it thinks it needs Kerberos it'll go and get a Kerberos ticket up front and send it first. The server might think that's fine, or it might fail and return a response saying
"no, I really need NTLM", and so the client tries again with NTLM.